# Port number is missing when page switches

Tags: java, tomcat6

I'm working on Java code setup in eclipse.created a dynamic web project.

I'm running the project via Apache tomcat server 6.0. able to run the code without any issues. But when I run the code the login page displays with the URL (local host:8080/example) after entering the logging in the URL is directed to (http://local host/example/home.jsp) and says page not found check the local host is correct .the same I'm able to access by manually entering port number in URL like (local host:8080/example/home.jsp.

The problem is if URL with port number it is working fine. But when page switches the URL is coming without port number.

Not able to access: localhost/example/home.jsp
Able to access: localhost:8080/example/home.jsp

Could you please let me know any server configurations I need to setup so it will automatically the port number is displayed when I switch the page.

Thanks

Comment: you can use default port 80 in your server configuration

Comment: But I want to know why -- *But when page switches the URL is coming without port number.*

Comment: You are doing something wrong when you "switch the page". Since you don't show us what you are doing, how do you expect us to be able to tell you what you are doing wrong? Edit the question and show the code where you build the redirect.

Comment: I'm not sure when run the code the login page URL is local host:8080/example. After entering the login information the home .jsp is URL is local host/example/home.jsp.

Comment: Perhaps you could share with us the code that runs on login (namely, the one that gives this URL to the browser) ?

Comment: I'm not sure when run the code the login page URL is local host:8080/example. After entering the login information the home .jsp is URL is local host/example/home.jsp. if I enter port number and refresh the home page is visible.

Comment: On which port do you want your server to run @ port 8080 or @ 80 (default)?

Comment: Default port..I'm not concerned about the port. After first login all other pages URL is pointing to local host / example/home.jsp without port number and browser says page not found.The same works with port number.manually I entered the port number in URL it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command and load the application.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`